# Mongoose + Typescript custom doc interface not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I have been working on mongoose + typescript for quite some time now.
But I am facing this issue while creating **CustomDoc interface** for my schema.

### Error

Typescript is not validating the returned document from mongoose query, it shows type **any**.

> **Custom Doc Interface**

```js
interface UserAttrs {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

interface UserDoc extends mongoose.Document {  // <== here
  name: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  isAdmin: Boolean;
  createdAt: Date;
}

interface UserModel extends mongoose.Model<UserDoc> {
  build: (attrs: UserAttrs) => UserDoc;
}

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    isAdmin: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },
  }
);
userSchema.statics.build = (attrs: UserAttrs) => {
  return new User(attrs);
};

export const User = mongoose.model<UserDoc, UserModel>("User", userSchema);
```

> **The error / issue**

[image]

As per my understanding, it should have a type of `UserDoc` or `undefined`.
That is the reason why I am not able validate while destructuring user properties off of user document, which makes no sense to use TS like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out instead:

```
interface UserAttrs {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

interface UserDoc extends UserAttrs, mongoose.Document {  
  isAdmin: Boolean;
  createdAt: Date;
}


const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    isAdmin: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },
  }
);
userSchema.statics.build = (attrs: UserAttrs) => {
  return new User(attrs);
};

export const User = mongoose.model<UserDoc>("User", userSchema);
```

Comment: Sadly it did not make any difference. :/